# Maintain the Relative Control's Position in WPF

Tags: wpf, user-controls, wpf-controls

I have a `Canvas` in which I have some UserControls.

You can imagine it as a Map with city points.

Say, the canvas size is 100x100.
Say I have only two UserControls A (10, 20) and B (50, 50).

Now, user resizes the canvas to 1000x1000.

Is there a way to keep the UserControls at the same scale: A(100, 200) and B(500, 500) WITHOUT cycle all the controls and updating its individual positions to the manually calculated new ones.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at my answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3530149/change-origin-of-canvas). If you have lat/longs for your cities it's ideal. If not, it sounds like you'd be best writing your own panel that uses relative coordinates rather than absolute.

Comment: I updated my post. I have a map with city points. So, I can't figure out a grid in the canvas place. More that than the points are linked with line connectors.

Comment: thank you. I don't use latitude longitude. My "map" is not geographical one, but more just schematical... So, I just need to drag some dots on a surface, but keep that dots at the same relative position when resizing. I don't see a difference in wrinting a custom panel vs canvas, so, I already try to do it, this because I posted my question.

Comment: @serhio: the difference is the panel will encapsulate the relative layout logic, whereas using a Canvas will require you to encapsulate that logic in a multi-converter, and bind each of your child items accordingly. Personally, I find the former option more attractive and reusable. But take your pick.